# unable to push each element that is named tab into an array after pulling the dom object

Tags: javascript

In the developer tools it shows that i was able to pull all the elements that i needed to but the issue is i cannot push them to the array, it stays empty. Unfortunately i am not allowed to use jquery. I have done so much research and just unable to find exactly what i need.

```
 /*

 Author:Anthony Weed
 Date:2/20/2015

Filename:  menus.js

*/
window.addEventListener('load',setTabs);

var currentTab = null;
var maxZ = 1;
var i=0;

function setTabs(){
var menuTabs = [];
var allElements = document.getElementById('page').getElementsByTagName('*');
    for(var i=0;  i < allElements.length; i++){
     if (allElements.children == 'LI.tab'){
        menuTabs.push(allElements[i]);
        }
     else {
     continue;
     }
     i++
     }
console.log(allElements);
console.log(menuTabs);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(var i=0;  i < allElements.length; i++){
 if (allElements.children == 'LI.tab'){
       var newAryElement = allElements[1];

       menuTabs.push(newAryElement);
    }
 i++
 }
```

This might not solve your problem, but I suspect that it will reveal newAryElement to be an array itself, which you will then need to parse.

Comment: yes, but the console returns that the newAryElement is undefined

Comment: Sorry, Anthony, I was asking @MichaelMcPherson if he had tried it.

Comment: That suggests, as Jonathan M says below, that there's an issue with your selector. Do go below and read his reference for getElementsByTagName(); it's going to help.

Comment: i was able to figure it out...all of the things yall said led me to right answer.
so in my if statement i put elements[i].className == 'tab' this then allowed me to push each tab into array.

Comment: You should type that up, and answer your own question, then!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
if (allElements.children == 'LI.tab'){
```

`allElements.children` is referencing something that isn't there. `allElements` is an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is kind of like an array, but it's an object.

I'm a little unclear in what you're trying to do, so I can't really offer a way to make this work, but this is certainly the problem. Depending on what you're trying to do, you might want to be referencing something like:

```
if (allElements.item(i).tagName == somethingHere ) {
```

Here's the reference for [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName).

Comment: that was a previous attempt to see if it would work...basically we are using javascript to create a tabbed nav bar. and each of the tab named li elements are the drop down headers.